# php string is appened to every request

Tags: php, apache

I've got a problem.  After moving a project to another server I get strange string "192" which is inserted before every response from server. I did no changes into source code and it works fine on another server. I've only copied project... Really. That's all.

This is how it looks:

[image]

[image]
[image]

It can be beared when dealing with generated pages. but json reponse is not correct so it gets broken because of this number "192".

In the root folder /var/www/html  I  have only this project. Nothing else.

I guess it must be something with php settings.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some code would be nice...

Comment: this is a big project.  It works fine on one server. So problem must be not with code, I suppose... Can it be caused by server settings?

Comment: The problem is with the code off course. Check the configuration files you are adding before executing any file of the view.

Comment: It could be both, or either. Once analysis of the code is done, then you can check server settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the code off course. Check the configuration files you are adding before executing any file of the view.

If you want to verify there is something wrong with the code, you may just put an `empty hello world` file and execute it from the browser. See if 192 comes there also or not.

Something like this on `/var/www/html/test.php`
`<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>`

Now run your website `http://yourwebsite.com/test.php` and share the output.

Comment: yes, it turned out that problem was with code. more pricesely - http://minus.com/i/bco5bvRnQcB5U  . Someone just type 192 number there... What a shame...

Answer (score 2):

If the 192 is not in your code (and since it doesn't show on a different server, it certainly seems so), another very strong contender from where it is coming from is the php.ini option, [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).

```
auto_prepend_file  string
    Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the 
    main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require 
    function, so include_path is used.
```

The easiest way to find out if there is a file being included before all of your requested pages is by searching the phpinfo() output for auto_prepend_file, and editing the php.ini file to remove it if it is there.